# joining 2 tables while including the nulls

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a table called Animals and another table that contains a mapping term for the animals.

**Animal table**
[image]

**Animal mapping table**
[image]

And I need the output table to correctly label each animal, and if there is no match, then it will return a NULL.

**Output table**
[image]

I was thinking of using an **outer join** (and also trying with **join**) with regexp_contains but it wouldn't print out any results. Any help will be nice. Thank you

```
select * from `animals` a
join `animals_label` m
on regexp_contains(lower(concat('[^a-zA-Z]', a.animals, '[^a-zA-Z]')) , lower(concat( 
'[^a-zA-Z]', m.label, '[^a-zA-Z]' )))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` the string and `join`:

```
select distinct animal, am.label
from animal a cross join
     unnest(split(a.animal, ' ')) animal left join
     animal_mapping am
     on am.animal = animal;
```

Comment: If I keep on getting an error "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join," how can we change it, since i think it because of the on statement?

Comment: @studentprogrammer . . . The condition should be `am.animal = animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select a.*, animal as extracted_animal, label
from animals a, 
(select string_agg(animal, '|') all_animals from animals_label) 
left join unnest(regexp_extract_all(animal, r'(?i)' || all_animals)) animal
left join animals_label
using(animal)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]